# get more than two foreign keys from another django table and perform calculations on them

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

In the Django app, I have created two tables.
Product
Invoice

I have one table called Product which contains product name and product price columns are given.

Then, I have a second table named Invoice which contains a product name(foreign key), product price(foreign key), discount, and total.

My concern is how can I import both the values from the Product table i.e. product name and product price and perform calculations on them. The structure is given below:

myapp ->
PRODUCT:
*Product Name
*Product Id
*Product Price

```
    INVOICE:
        *Product Name (foreign key)
        *Product Id (foreign key)
        *Product Price (foreign key)
        *Discount
        *Total = Product Price - Discount
```

how can I import values and perform further calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use the product as a foreign key inside the `Invoice`. You do not need all fields to be mentioned inside `Invoice`. If you want to access them you can do so by `invoice.product.name, price or id` ( using invoice instance). Let me give you an overview of how it will look like

```
class Product(db.Model):
"""
Product details
"""

class Invoice(db.Model)
"""
invoice details 
"""

product = db.ForeignKey(Product, related_name= "invoices", **other_fields)
```

Now for example if you need a name, id, or any other field from the product for a specific invoice. Then first you have to query the invoice and get an instance from the invoice table and then gets related product details

Code example:

```
invoice = Invoice.objects.filter(**filter_conditions).first()
```

Now do further logic on the product using below format

```
invoice.product.id
invoice.product.name
invoice.product.price

and any other logic that needs to be done here it goes.
```

That is how you can achieve what you want to achieve here.

Comment: That's a good idea!  but my further question was, what about performing operations upon the fields in the model? can we do it in the model section itself, or do we have to use forms for it?

Comment: I will suggest better creating a small scr function inside the Invoice and do the logical task related to it there or in the product. that way you just need to call then line invoice. get_this or that.